# Building jEdit in Netbeans: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jedit

I'm tyring to build jEdit in Netbeans in Windows and was getting the 
following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class 
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner Running
>   org.jedit.io.Native2ASCIIEncodingTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 0,
>   Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec Test
>   org.jedit.io.Native2ASCIIEncodingTest FAILED (crashed)

```
JAVA version: 1.8
Ant: 1.9.4
```

I've also defined the following source classes:

```
lib\compile\jsr305.jar
lib\docbook\xml-apis.jar
lib\test\hamcrest-core.jar
lib\test\hamcrest-library.jar
lib\test\junit-dep.jar
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have the Ant Optional package as directed by the README.SRC.txt?

Comment: Should that come with the package? I can find an optional folder in it: \apache-ant-1.9.4\manual\api\org\apache\tools\ant\taskdefs\optional

Comment: That's just the manual part, but do you have the actual optional package? And does it build from the command line?

Comment: I tried putting the ant-optional jar but had no success. Ended up using Intellij to build it and it was successful. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It's the much better IDE anyway. :-D